# How to connect to Oracle 11g database remotely

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have Oracle 11g XE installed on computer A. I can connect through the sql command line using the command `connect username/password`. I also can send SQL instructions to the Demo database: `Select * from demo_customers;`

The database is running on localhost of computer A.

I want computer B to connect to computer A's database on localhost. How can I do that?

Answer (score 15):

You will need to run the lsnrctl utility on server A to start the listener. You would then connect from computer B using the following syntax:

```
sqlplus username/password@hostA:1521 /XE
```

The port information is optional if the default of 1521 is used.

[Listener configuration documentation here.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/network.htm#ADMQS156)
[Remote connection documentation here.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/connecting.htm#CEGIGEIJ)

Answer (score 6):

I install the Oracle server and it allows to connect from the local machine with no problem. But from another Maclaptop on my home network, it can't connect using either Sql Developer or Sql Plus. After doing some research, I figured out there is this additional step you have to do:

Use the Oracle net manager. Select the Listener. Add the IP address  (in my case it is 192.168.1.12) besides of the 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

This will end up add an entry to the  [OracleHome]\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora

- restart the listener service. (note: for me I reboot machine once to make it work)
- Use lsnrctl status to verify
  Notice the additional HOST=192.168.1.12 shows up and this is what to make remote connection to work.

  > C:\Windows\System32>**lsnrctl status**
  >   LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 05-SEP-2015 13:51:43
  >     Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
  >     Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  >      STATUS of the LISTENER
  >
  > ---
  >
  > Alias                     LISTENER
  >      Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 -     Production
  >      Start Date                05-SEP-2015 13:45:18
  >      Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 6 min. 24 sec
  >      Trace Level               off
  >      Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
  >      SNMP                      OFF
  >      Listener Parameter File
  >      D:\oracle11gr2\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
  >      Listener Log File         d:\oracle11gr2\diag\tnslsnr\eagleii\listener\alert\log.xml
  >      Listening Endpoints Summary...
  >        (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  >        (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  >        (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.1.12)(PORT=1521)))
  >      Services Summary...
  >      Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  >        Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  >      Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  >        Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  >      Service "xeXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  >        Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  >      The command completed successfully
- use **tnsping**  to test the connection
  ping the IPv4 address, not the localhost or the 127.0.0.1

> C:\Windows\System32>tnsping  192.168.1.12
>      TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 05-SEP-2015 14:09:11
>      Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>      Used parameter files:
>      D:\oracle11gr2\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
>
> Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
>   Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.12)(PORT=1521)))
>   OK (0 msec)

Comment: Great and as simple as possible.

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure the **listener** on database server (computer A) that receives client connection requests is running. To do so, run `lsnrctl status` command.

In case, if you get `TNS:no listener` message (see below image), it means listener service is not running. To start it, run `lsnrctl start` command.

[image]

Second, for database operations and connectivity from remote clients, the following executables must be added to the Windows Firewall exception list: (see image)

***Oracle_home\bin\oracle.exe - Oracle Database executable***

***Oracle_home\bin\tnslsnr.exe - Oracle Listener***

[image]

Finally, install **oracle instant client** on client machine (computer B) and run:

`sqlplus user/password@computerA:port/XE`

Answer (score 5):

Its quite easy on computer a you don't need to do anything just make sure both system are on same network if its not internet access(for this you need static ip). Okay now on computer b go to start menu find configuration under oracle folder click Net Configuration Assistant under that folder when window pop up click Local net configuration option it must be third option.

Now click add and click next in next screen it will ask service name here you need to add oracle global database name of computer A(Normally I use oracle86 for my installation) now click next next screen choose protocol normally its tcp click next in host name enter computer A's name you can found that in my computer properties. Click next don't change port untill you have changed that in Computer A click next and choose test connection now here you can check your connection working or not if the error is username and password not correct then click login credential button and fill correct username and password. If its saying unable to reach computer ot target not found than you must add exception in firewall for 1521 port or just disable firewall on computer A.

Answer (score 4):

**First.**
It is necessary add static IP address for Computer A AND B.
For example in my case Computer A (172.20.14.13) and B (172.20.14.78).

**Second.** 
In Computer A with Net Manager add for Listener new address (172.20.14.13)  or manually add new record in listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = E:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:E:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.20.14.13)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = E:\app\user
```

**Third.**
With Net Manager create Service Naming with IP address computer B (172.20.14.78) or manually add new record in  tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ALINADB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = alinadb)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ALINADB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


LOCAL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.20.14.13)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = alinadb)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.20.14.78)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

**Fourth.**
In computer  B (172.20.14.78) install  win64_11gR2_client (For example it is for me in Windows 10  Pro 64 bit )

Five. 
Create with Net Configuration Assistant listener (localhost) or manually add record  in listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: F:\app\alinasoft\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

    LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myserver)(PORT = 1521))
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
        )
      )

    ADR_BASE_LISTENER = F:\app\alinasoft
```

**Six.**
With Net Manager create Service Naming with IP address computer 
 A (172.20.14.13) or manually add new record in  tnsnames.ora.

```
SERVER-DB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.20.14.13)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = alinadb)
    )
  )
```

**Seven**
(Computer A - (172.20.14.13)) for database operations and connectivity from remote clients, the following executables must be added to the Windows Firewall exception list: (see image)
Oracle_home\bin\oracle.exe - Oracle Database executable
Oracle_home\bin\tnslsnr.exe - Oracle Listener

**Eight** 
Allow  connections  for port 1158 (Computer A - (172.20.14.13))   for Oracle  Enterprise Manager  (https://172.20.14.13:1158/em/console/logon/logon)

**Ninth** 
Allow  connections  for port 1521 ( in and out) (Computer A - (172.20.14.17))

**Tenth** 
In computer B 172.20.14.78
sqlplus /NOLOG 
CONNECT system/oracle@//172.20.14.13:1521/alinadb

If uses Toad, in my case is 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
# . /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh  

#  sqlplus /nolog  

SQL> connect sys/password as sysdba                                           

SQL>  EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);  

SQL> CONNECT sys/password@hostname:1521 as sysdba
```