# How do I configure a Windows task to ping database every few minutes

Tags: oracle11g, windows-server-2008-r2, ping, windows-task-scheduler, taskscheduler

The firewall setting at the server breaks the connection to an application I am using every 2 hours it sees it idle.

How to i write/configure a task from Windows Scheduler to Ping the database every 30 minutes so that the Firewall is not able to break the connection.

I know I need to use the query "select * from dual"

But I am beginner with zero experience on windows administrative tools.

Can someone please help me, how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Download `SQL*Plus` from the Oracle website (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)

Then create a bat file with the `select * from dual` command.
Create a scheduled task that runs the command, such as:

```
sqlplus user/password @query.sql
```

I would however get your firewall configured correctly.

Comment: thanks @Lock , does that mean I need to create a task in which the .bat (batch file) runs at fixed intervals (since it has the query to ping Database).

Comment: Correct. Place the script anywhere (such as c:\scripts) and simply schedule this task to run at whatever your required interval is.

Answer (score 0):

This explains how to schedule a task:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

This explains how to connect to Oracle from the command line.
[How to connect to Oracle 11g database remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108320/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11g-database-remotely)

When configuring the action for the task, use `sqlplus` in the "Program/Script" field and `username/password@hostA:1521 /XE` for "Add arguments (optional)".